# Not able to remove input using removeUI

Tags: r, shiny

I have two inputs to be removed from the ui.R

```
fileInput(inputId = "FileInput",label = "Choose a csv file",accept = '.csv'),
uiOutput("SKU")
```

Inside server i am using an `observeEvent` to remove these `2 inputs` and insert one. Though the `insertUi` is working I am not able to remove `the other 2`.

**PFB** the code:

```
observeEvent(input$Save,{
    removeUI(
      selector = "div:has(> #FileInput)"     
    )
    insertUI(
      selector = "#Save",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui =fluidPage( 
        tags$hr(),
        fluidRow(column(offset=0,1,actionButton("clean","Start cleaning the Data")))
      )
    )  
    })
```

Comment: please provide the complete code.

Comment: That is the code. I have two input (fileInput and uiOutput) and I want to remove the 2 using removeUI().

Comment: chances are higher you get an answer if you provide a complete app, how else should it be tested,...just saying

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to treat it the same way in which the [shiny blog example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) treats text by wrapping it in a div with id.

```
tags$div(
    fileInput(inputId = "FileInput",label = "Choose a csv file",accept = '.csv'),
    id='FileInput'
)
```

**Example**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
     tags$div(fileInput('element1','Input file...'),id='element1'),
     actionButton('remove','Remove File Input')
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$remove,{
     removeUI(selector = '#element1')
   })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```