# Issues while displaying the dataset and unloading previous operations

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I have few issues in the app here. This is the code wherein I `add` and Load csv files. But There are some issues and also I require few things. Request anyone to help me

Issues : 
1) I am not able to load second file. Not sure why?
2) I have added the remove button as well, so that Once `Remove` button is clicked the respective file should be unloaded. 
3) Can we create another output where as and when new file is load, it should display first 15 rows `head(df, n = 6)`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
actionButton("add", "Add UI",width = 100)

observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = c( "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv"))
      ,multiple = FALSE
    )
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = actionButton("V","Remove",width = 100))
  })
observeEvent(input$V,{
     removeUI(selector = '#file1')
   }) 
```
````

Comment: This may help in `removeUI` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548083/not-able-to-remove-input-using-removeui

Comment: I tried but not working. I have edited my question. Also, there are other issues as well. Like 1) I am not able to load second file. Not sure why? 2 ) Can we create another output where as and when new file is load, it should display first 15 rows head(df, n = 6). Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here a different design I hope it helps

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
actionButton("add", "Add UI",width = 100)
observeEvent(input$add, {
  remove_id <- paste0("remove_", input$add)
  insertUI(
    selector = "#add",
    where = "afterEnd",
    ui = tags$div(fileInput(paste0("file",input$add), paste0("Choose CSV File", input$add), accept = c( "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")),
                  actionButton(remove_id, paste0("Remove",input$add), width = 100), id=remove_id), multiple = FALSE)

observeEvent(input[[remove_id]],{
  removeUI(selector = paste0("#",remove_id), immediate = TRUE, multiple = TRUE)
})
})

```
````

Comment: Hi Suliman. Thanks a lot. Actually I also tried this. But if you observe carefully, when you click on Add twice/twice and so on , you cannot load 2 datasets. Some bug is there that I am not able to fiqure out. Please try once.